# Excessive editing of a post

Tags: support, specific-question, editing

This revision was approved:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/201726/6

How do I protest a revision?

I am still indicated as the author of the question, but it has been rewritten to remove all my words. I am no longer the author of the question.

Questions that are **3 years** old should be locked to prevent such a large rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Editing and collaboration](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/editing) are fundamental parts of Stack Exchange. Except for rare cases of content disputes (a large number of edits and rollbacks or Meta discussion on a particular post's quality) or historical protection of posts that would otherwise be deleted, all posts can be edited. However, we do have guidance for editing - edits should fix grammar or spelling, clarifying the meaning, incorporate information from comments, add updates as the post ages, or add related links.

I reviewed the edit and saw that it didn't meet the criteria. It changed the words without accomplishing any of the objectives for edits - it didn't become more clear or incorporate new information or add anything of value. Because of this, I [rolled the edit back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback). Anyone with edit rights to a post can also use this rollback function.

In the future, if you see anything wrong, here are things that you can do:

- Fix it. At 2,000 reputation, you have the ability to edit questions and answers without review. Prior to this, you can make edits and put them into a review queue for people with sufficient reputation to review. By this point, you've also gained other editing capabilities - creating new tags (300), editing community wiki (100), and commenting (50).
- [Flag it for moderator review](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/flagging). If you suspect that something bad is happening, please flag it. We review our flags very regularly and handle things. We have lots of good tools to help us.
- Bring it up on Meta, like you did here. If you don't need a moderator to handle it or something needs broader discussion by the community, open a discussion. Moderators are also notified of all new Meta posts, so if it requires our input or review, we'll see it and should be able to look into it.

Comment: The original author has broad powers to fix this problem.  Any original author can roll back revisions and unilaterally reject suggested edits *to their own post,* regardless of their rep level.